# Run-time Error 5: Invalid Procedure - Changing Pivot Table Source

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I'm getting the `"Run-time error '5': Invalid Procedure call or argument at the line below in blue: PT1.ChangePivotCache ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PTSourceRngFcst, Version:=6)`

These are the values of the cells listed in the code:

```
    G24 = \\hguwarps03\WarrenData\Finance\MANAGEMENT_REPORTS\Reforecast 2019\P06_19-Jun Reforecast\
    G25 = fncl-analysis-data_May-29.xlsx
    G26 = L:\Finance\MANAGEMENT_REPORTS\Reforecast 2019\P06_19-Jun Reforecast\[fncl-analysis-data_May-29.xlsx]fncl-analysis-data
```

```
Sub Update_Sources()
'
Dim wb As Workbook, wbFromFcst As Workbook, wbFromReFcst As Workbook
Dim wkshtSourceFcst As Worksheet, wkshtSourceReFcst As Worksheet
Dim fromPathFcst As String
Dim SourceNameFcst As String
Dim PTSourcePathFcst As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim StartPointFcst As Range
Dim PTSourceRngFcst As String
Dim PT1 As PivotTable


Set wb = ThisWorkbook


fromPathFcst = Sheets("CONTROLS").Range("G24")
SourceNameFcst = Sheets("CONTROLS").Range("G25")
PTSourcePathFcst = Sheets("CONTROLS").Range("G26")


Set wbFromFcst = Workbooks.Open(fromPathFcst & SourceNameFcst)
Set wkshtSourceFcst = wbFromFcst.Sheets("fncl-analysis-data")
Set StartPointFcst = wkshtSourceFcst.Range("A1")
Set rng = wkshtSourceFcst.Range(StartPointFcst, 
StartPointFcst.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
PTSourceRngFcst = PTSourcePathFcst & "!" & 
rng.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)


Set PT1 = 
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pivots").PivotTables("Customer_Cat_LocnType")


PT1.ChangePivotCache 
ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, 
SourceData:=PTSourceRngFcst, Version:=6)
'This is where I get the error







End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below to set the `PivotCache` and then update the Pivot-Table with the updated `PivotCache`

```
Dim PT1 As PivotTable
Dim PTCache As PivotCache '<-- define new Pivot-Cahce Object

' set the Range Address as String
PTSourceRngFcst = Rng.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)

' set the Pivot Cache
Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PTSourceRngFcst)

' set The Pivot Table object
Set PT1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pivots").PivotTables("Customer_Cat_LocnType")

' refresh the Pivot Cache
PT1.ChangePivotCache PTCache
PT1.RefreshTable
```

Comment: I got the same "Run-time error '5': Invalid Procedure call or argument error at:
    PT1.ChangePivotCache PTCache

Comment: Hi Shai. Did you see my last comment? I got the Run-time error '5' at: PT.ChangePivotCache PTCache line. Is there something I'm missing? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JonD. the error must be coming from somewhere else. if you add a line `Debug.Print PTSourceRngFcst` right after `PTSourceRngFcst = Rng.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)` , what do you get in the immediate window ?

Comment: `'[fncl-analysis-data_May-30.xlsx]fncl-analysis-data'!A1:CZ177422`

Comment: @JonD. you should edit your post, maybe check that this data is organized correctly. and your Pivot-Table name is "Customer_Cat_LocnType") and placed in the right sheet

Answer (score 0):

Was also getting the same error for the ChangePivotCache line in my VBA script, and could not find a solution elsewhere so posting here for future reference. In my case, it turned out out to be that the pivot table whose PivotCache I was trying to change had a shared filter connection with another pivot table. I resolved by disconnecting the slicer from the table before running the script. Then script ran successfully.

```
Sub decouple_pivot_table()

    ' A pivot table cache can only be changed if it does not share a filter
    ' connection with another table. If attempting to change the data source
    ' of a pivot table with a shared filter connection, the macro will throw
    ' a Run-Time error 5 for invalid procedure.
    
    ' Bottom Line: Not possible to have DIFFERENT data sources AND SHARED filter
    
    Dim PTtab As PivotTable
    Dim PTtabNew As PivotTable
    
    Debug.Print "Starting"
    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Count
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("template")
    
        Set PTtab = .PivotTables("test")
        PTtab.TableRange2.Copy .Range("A25")
        
        .Range("A25").Activate
        ActiveCell.PivotTable.Name = "DecoupledTable"
        Set PTtabNew = .PivotTables("DecoupledTable")
        PTtabNew.ChangePivotCache _
            ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
            SourceData:=Range("data!A1:C100"), Version:=8)
        
        PTtabNew.RefreshTable
        
    End With
        
    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Count
    Debug.Print "Passed"

End Sub
```

Note that when attempting to manually change the data source, the error is much more informative:

'The data source of a PivotTable connected to filter controls that are also connected to other PivotTables cannot be changed. To change the data source, first disconnect the filter controls from this PivotTable or from the other PivotTables'